# PHP - Not echoing data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a PHP comments section. I got to the point where it will store the comments in the database, but when I try to echo them on the screen, nothing shows up. Also, it makes a duplicate of the previous comment.

Here is my PHP

```
function setComments($conn) {
    if(isset($_POST['comment_submit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result(fetch_assoc())) {
        echo $row['uid']." on ";
        echo $row['date']."<br/>";
        echo $row['message']."<br/> <br/>";
    }
}
```

Also, I know MySQL injection is a threat right now, but I'm adding protection to it later, so just ignore it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Did you not read the post? @tadman

Comment: date is a reserved word, so do not use that as field name https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @JordanBaron You can add your little caveat there but it doesn't change the fact this is terribly messy. Doing it right doesn't take a lot more code, and it ensures you won't be battling trivial little mistakes in the future. Writing out a disclaimer like that takes *more time* than fixing the problem.

Comment: Place your database connection also

Comment: @JordanBaron check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the getComments function,

```
<?php
    function getComments($conn) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
            echo $row['uid']." on ";
            echo $row['date']."<br/>";
            echo $row['message']."<br/> <br/>";
        }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't make anything appear either. :/

Comment: Have you check the MySQL table, does it contain data?

Comment: It always has. That wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your problem with showing comments. I tested it on my server and it's work.

```
function getComments($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['uid']." on ";
            echo $row['date']."<br/>";
            echo $row['message']."<br/> <br/>"; 
        }
    }
}    
getComments($conn);
```